# Pass Uint8List from dart to java over a TCPSocket

Tags: java, sockets, dart

I need to pass an `Uint8List` to a `byte[]` array in java over a TCPSocket. There is size mismatch at both ends. PS: I am a beginner in dart.

I have tried `socket.add(buf)`, `socket.write(buf)`, `socket.writeAll(buf)` but none of them worked

Code in Flutter side (TCP client)

```
 void readVoiceData(Uint8List buf) {    
     print("Send data size:"+buf.lengthInBytes.toString());    
     socket.add(buf);   
 }
```

> OUTPUT: Send data size: 1280

Code Snippet on java side (TCP server)

```
in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());  
    Log.d(TAG, "****Opened InputStream*******");
     while (!isInterrupted()) {                   
     if (mTrack != null) {
     try {
     in.read(bytes);        
     Log.d(TAG, "Received data size"+bytes.length);                                    
                                }
}
```

> OUTPUT: Received data size: 1

I am sure the socket connection has been established correctly as I am able to send Strings and Integers flawlessly over them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `read()` method of the `FilterInputStream` (`DataInput` is his son) reads [just the next avaliable byte](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html#read()).
Thou, if you want to get the total size of the InputStream, do something like:

```
  size = in.available(); //returns an estimate of number of bytes avaliable on the stream
  buf = new byte[size]; 
  realLength= in.read(buf, 0, size);
```

This code snippet is taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/GetbytesfromInputStream.htm).